# Tiling a $2×N$ rectangle with $1×1$ and $2×1$ tiles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, tiling

A $2×N$ rectangle is to be tiled with $1×1$, $1×2$ and $2×1$ tiles. Prove that there is an $x$ such that the number of possible tilings tends to $kx^N$ as $N$ gets large. Find $x$, to $2$ decimal places.

I tried to solve the problem initially by sketching all the possible tilings for $n=1,2,3,..$ but I realised this isn't a practical way to solve the problem.

Comment: Try to write a linear recursion first by columns, and put it in its matrix form. Perhaps eigenvalues would help there.

Comment: It is due to be connected to Fibonacci numbers. Have a look for example at (https://www.dartmouth.edu/~academicoutreach/docs/fibonacci-numbers-and-tiling.pdf). Besides, I am surprised by the $1 \times 1$. Isn't it $1 \times 2$ ?

Comment: Are you allowed to flip the $2\times 1$ tile? i.e do both $2 \times 1$ and $1\times 2$ tiles allowed? If not, the number of possible tilings is trivial.

Comment: Yes you are allowed to flip the tiles

Comment: Yes, you can use $1 \times 1$ tiles, $2 \times1$ tiles, and $1 \times 2$ tiles.

Comment: Look at the refs in [OEIS A030186](http://oeis.org/A030186).

Comment: @JeanMarie I also wonder if it not $1 \times 2$, case in which it unveils the usual Fibonacci sequence. However, if he is right, at last we get something different for once !

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus We can use $1\times1,2\times1$ and $1\times2$ tiles.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A030186 -- which suggests $x\approx3.2143$ (the largest real root of $x^3-3x^2-x+1$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to do some drawings here, but it will be a good exercise to do it on your own ^^

I follow what Philcar said: you can model the problem with a linear recursion. If you only can tile with $1\times 2$ and $2\times 1$, you get the classical tiling problem which leads to Fibonacci numbers and is equivalent to $k\phi^N$ with $\phi$ the golden ratio (1.618...). More generally, if you reach a linear recursion for the number of possible tilings, you will end with a $kx^N$ as awaited. Let us do the job for your case now.

Denote by $R_N$ the $2\times N$ rectangle you want to tile, $T_N$ the number of possible tilings with $1\times 1$, $1\times 2$ or $2\times 1$ tiles, and $L_N$ the possible tilings for a $2\times N$ rectangle with a $1\times 1$ tile at the bottom right (it appears naturally in the computations, see below). What can be said about the tilings of $R_N$ for a given $N$? Suppose you have such a tiling, and just look at the bottom right corner (the $1\times 1$ corner placed at $(2, N)$ with matrix notations:

- **either you get a $2\times 1$ tile**, that is a tile filling the last column. Searching possible ways to fill in the rest is the same as searching tilings for $R_{N-1}$ (the remaining places): so you get $T_{N-1}$ such tilings by definition;
- **or you get a $1\times 1$ tile**, and you get $L_N$ by definition;
- **or you get a $1 \times 2$ tile**. We can either get a $1\times 2$ tile above it, in which case you get $T_{N-2}$ possibilities for the remaining rectangle $R_{N-2}$; or one $1\times 1$ tile above it at the upper right corner (which create an "L"), and you get $L_{N-1}$ possibilities by definition.

At last you end up with a twisted linear recursion for $(T_N,L_N)$:

$$
\forall N \in \mathbf{N}, N \geqslant 2,
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
T_N = T_{N-1} + T_{N-2} + L_N + L_{N-1} \\
L_N = T_{N-1} + L_{N-1}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

From those two relations, we get $T_{N-1} + L_{N-1} = L_N = T_N - T_{N-2} -L_N$ so that:

$$L_N = \frac{T_N - T_{N-2}}{2}$$

which gives you the sought recursion:

$$T_N = 3T_{N-1} + T_{N-2} -T_{N-3}$$

So the characteristic equation has three distinct solutions (the paradisiac case), which can be explicited and the greater one is about $\mathbf{x=3.21}$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3%3D3x%5E2%2Bx-1)).

Now if you want to determine the constant $k$, you have to write down the general solution as $T_N = k_1x_1^N + k_2x_2^N + kx^N$ ($x_1$ and $x_2$ being the two other solutions, and use the first values of $T_N$ computed by hand ($N=0, 1, 2$ are easy and sufficient) to determine the constants, in particular the relevant $k$ (but here, you have to use the exact solutions).

Comment: The third bullet point with a $1\times2$ tile doesn't quite make sense to me, is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Hogg Take you rectangle $R_N$, you want to tile it. We suppose in this third case that there is a $1\times2$ tile at the bottom right corner. Now, what can happen above it, that is at the top right corner ? There is place either to a 1x2 tile (and you get a $R_{N-2}$ rectangle remaining, so $T_{N-2}$ possibilities for tiling the rest), or to a 1x1, in which case the remainder to tile is... A rectangle from which we substracted an L, as in the second bullet point (but with size one less), right ? Draw a picture, and tell me if you see it!

Comment: You can either have a $1\times2$ tile directly above it, or two $1\times1$ tiles above it. Also, should it say $T_{N-2},R_{N-2}$ instead of $T_{N-1},R_{N-1}$

Comment: @Hogg No, there is another possibility: On tile 1x1 above it, then a 1x2, it gives an L of size n-2. There is no reason for having a 1x1 tile at the place $(1, N-1)$ if you put a 1x1 at $(1,N)$, you can have something else (in this case a 1x2)

Comment: @Hogg We actually discrimine only on what happens on the place $(1,N)$, provided you have the bottom right filled with a tile $1\times 2$. There cannot be a tile $2\times 1$ (not enough place for it, for the place juste below is already filled), hence it remains the two other possibilities : a $1\times 2$ (which gives $T_{N-2}$) and a $1\times 1$ (which gives a $L_{N-1}$). You do not have to understand for the remaining places, it would juste will create more distinctions of cases and more trickier computations: this one suffice.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Could you explain the recursion $L_N=T_{N-1}+L_{N-1}$

Comment: @Hogg It is the same work as above: you consider your rectangle endowed with the 1x1 tile at the bottom right. What can happen above it? Either a 1x1 tile (in which case it remains a rectangle of type $R_{N-1}$, that is to say $T_{N-1}$ possibilities), or a 1x2 tile (in which case you get a new "L" of size one less, and then $L_{N-1}$ possibilities)

Comment: Why did you think to introduce $L_N$. It isn't intuitive.

Comment: @Hogg Well, I didn't at first, and I wasn't thinking to need some intermediate quantity like that...  but it arose naturally during the computations, I couldn't avoid it... hence I introduced it. It it where the intuition lacks of lucidity and formality allows going further ;) Do you see why when you try ? When you get an "L" (for instance with an 1x1 at the bottom left, you cannot guarantee getting rid of it after one tile more: if you put a 1x2, you get another "L" (smaller, from where we get the idea of finding a recursion relation). Is at least the formal solution satisfying you?

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus I still do no get the bullet on the 1x2 tile. You say if we have an 1x2 above it, we get T_(n-1) for a R_(n-2) rect, but that would make it all n-2, isn't it?
Also, the recurrence relations only make sense for me if it's n-2.

Comment: @Sasszem Indeed, that was a typo, thanks. I edited the answer, the recurrence relation still holds as stated.

Answer (score 1):

For each $2\times 1$ column, your choices are determined by how many rows are continuing a previous $1\times 2$ brick.  Initially neither row is (call this state ${\mathsf{0}}$).  When neither row is, you may place a $2\times 1$ brick (staying in ${\mathsf{0}}$).  Also, each row continuing a previous $1\times 2$ brick must be completed, and each row not continuing a previous $1\times 2$ brick may be used to start a $1\times 2$ brick or to place a $1\times 1$ brick.  So your choices are: ${\mathsf{0}}\rightarrow {\mathsf{0}}\;(\times 2),{\mathsf{1}}\;(\times 2),{\mathsf{2}}$; ${\mathsf{1}}\rightarrow {\mathsf{0}},{\mathsf{1}}$; and ${\mathsf{2}}\rightarrow {\mathsf{0}}$.  Since you start in state ${\mathsf{0}}$, the number of ways to be in each state after $N$ columns is given by:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)^N\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\0
\end{matrix}\right)\sim u_1\lambda_1^N,
$$
where $\lambda_1\approx 3.21432$ is the largest eigenvalue of the matrix being raised to the $N$-th power.  In particular, the number of ways to close off the rectangle is equal to the number of ways of being back in state $\mathsf{0}$, still asymptotic to a constant times $\lambda_1^N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain the sentence "So your choices are: $0→0 (×2),1 (×2), 2; 1→0, 1$; and $2→0$".

Comment: Yes.  If the state is 0 (neither row in the middle of a horizontal brick), you can place a vertical brick or two little square bricks, leaving the state 0 (in x2 different ways); or you can place one little square brick and one horizontal brick, changing the state to 1 (in x2 different ways, because the little brick can be in either row); or you can place two horizontal bricks, changing the state to 2. ...

Comment: ... If the state is 1 (exactly one row in the middle of a horizontal brick), you must complete the horizontal brick, and may place either a little square brick or a new horizontal brick in the other row (causing the state to be 0 or 1, respectively).  Finally, if the state is 2 (both rows in the middle of horizontal bricks), you must complete both, taking the state to 0.