# Tiling a N×M rectangle with 1×1, 1x2 and 2×1 tiles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recurrence-relations, tiling

I have read articles explaining the solution to the ways to tile a 2xM rectangle, but I'm not able to think the recursive ecuations for the general case.

I tried to solve the problem initially by sketching all the possible tilings for n and m <=3
but I realised this isn't a practical way to solve the problem.

The link with the solution to 2xM size of rectangle.
[Tiling a $2×N$ rectangle with $1×1$ and $2×1$ tiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958611/tiling-a-2%C3%97n-rectangle-with-1%C3%971-and-2%C3%971-tiles/2054340)

I need to find the solutions to a 3xM ,4xM,..8xM size of rectangles.

Comment: Are you saying there is a solution that you don't understand?  If so, please give us the solution, and explain what part is giving you difficulty.

Comment: Do you want one solution or be able to find all solutions ?

Comment: I'm asking for a way to find the ways to tile a 3xM ,4xM,5xM, etc
Or just for the recursive ecuations.